# Why don't we have a formula to explain how to integrate (find the anti-derivative) of $\sqrt [n] {x^m}$ over the variable $x$?

Tags: calculus, integration

In maths, it is easier to remember formulas to calculate specific expressions rather than using the steps to calculate the expression, because unlike memorising the formulas, doing the steps takes time. For example: $$(a \pm b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 \pm 2ab$$
The steps in this example is denoted as $FOIL$ (First, Outer, Inner, Last) because we expand $(a \pm b)^2$ as $(a \pm b)(a \pm b)$. In a way, it is like memorising your times tables. For example, $12 \times 6 = 72$. I know that because I memorised it. I don't need to do $\underbrace{12 + 12 + \cdots + 12}_{\text{6 times}}$

Because of this, why haven't I seen an equation similar to the following? $$\int \sqrt [n] {x^m}\ \text{d}x = R\bigg(1 + \frac{m}{n}\bigg)x^{1 + m/n}$$ for which $R$ denotes the *reciprocal function* $(\text{r.f})$. To explain, the $\text{r.f}$ is in front of the expression $1 + m/n$, so this is telling you to "invert (flip) $1 + m/n$ after converting it to a fraction".

I don't think the $\text{r.f}$ exists, because I just made it up since it looks nice in my opinion. (The symbol $\ni$ looks ugly in my opinion as well. In fact, the proper *reciprocal function* already exists which is $f(x) = 1/x$.) I just memorise this formula in my head and I always get the answer. For example, substitute $m = 1$ and $n = 2$ then $$\int \sqrt{x}\ \text{d}x = R\bigg(1 + \frac{1}{2}\bigg)x^{1 + 1/2} = R\bigg(\frac{3}{2}\bigg)x^{3/2} = \frac{2\sqrt{x^3}}{3}$$

I discussed this with my friend and he just said, "You do you. Whatever works for you mate." I am not asking for there to be another reciprocal function (if there does not exist one apart from the one I use which isn't even in the books!). All I am asking is *why isn't there a (minor) formula like the one I use?*

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this just the power rule? $\sqrt[n]{x^m} = x^{m/n}$ ergo an anti-derivative is $\frac{1}{1+m/n}x^{1+m/n}$ for $m/n\neq -1$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_rule

Comment: What is the power rule?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the problem here. In general for $p\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{-1\}$,we have $\int x^p dx=\frac{x^{p+1}}{p+1}+c$ and for $p=-1$, the integral is $\log x + c$, where $c$ is the constant of integration. So we do have a formula. In fact unlike yours, this works for even irrational numbers.

Comment: Why did I not know this????

Comment: I don't think I understand, what is wrong with $(1+\frac{m}{n})^{-1}$? Also this is just a special case of integrating $x^r$, $r $ a really number, which I have seen all over the place.

Comment: Ok let $p = -1$ then integrating, we have $\dfrac{x^0}{0}$ which obviously does not work. I see why we cannot let $p = -1$....so then how do we integrate? Is there a solution? Woops sorry, didn't see the comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that 
$$
\int x^\alpha=\frac{x^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+1}+C
$$
for any $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{ -1 \}$, so it certainly holds in this case.

Comment: What is $c$? I am assuming that is a constant because the derivative of $x^a$ is $ax^{a - 1}$ so obviously the integral must do $\dfrac{x^{a + 1}}{a + 1}$ to serve as the *anti-deriviative*. So is $c$ just a constant then?

Comment: yes, the constant of integration

Comment: Ok awesome so this does not seem too hard!!! :) PS. Yes that was $-1$ by the way which I was going to point out because $a \neq -1$.....but why?

Comment: first of all, the formula is undefined there. Second, the integral of $1/x$ is (even often defined as) $\ln x$.

Comment: Ok. I guess this was a dumb question then, but I learnt some important stuff -- the BASICS! Anyway, congratz @qbert $$(+1) \ \ \ \color{green}{\checkmark}$$

Comment: And it turns out there is a thing called the *Arf Invariant* anyway, but since $R$ isn't a real thing, I will just call it $\text{r.f}$ just to be original.